# How to avoid when unpublishing a Component, that all embedded Components are also unpublished in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, event-system

How can we avoid when unpublishing a Component, that all embedded Components are also unpublished in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?

I have tried to fix it by using the following event system code, but it is not working when unpublishing the Component. I mean when we click on the unpublish button which event should be triggered?

```
public DisableComponentLinkResolving()
{
    InitializeEvent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes the event, binding it to when a component is submitted 
/// for publishing (old OnComponentSavePre event)
/// </summary>
private void InitializeEvent()
{                       
    EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, UnPublishEventArgs>(
                                           ComponentUnpublish, EventPhases.Initiated);
}

private void ComponentUnpublish(Component component, 
                                UnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
{
    Logger.Write("Into ComponentUnpublish UnPublishEventArgs");
    if (IsLinkDisabled(component))
    {
        Logger.Write("Into ComponentUnpublish UnPublishEventArgs- -" 
                                                    + component.Id.ToString());

        args.UnPublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks = false;
        Logger.Write("Out of ComponentUnpublish UnPublishEventArgs- -" 
                                                    + component.Id.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a question? or are you just sharing your solution?

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange! When posting a question it's always useful to provide enough information as possible giving people a chance to answer. You're question at present is unclear, are you asking how to prevent unpublishing of component links when unpublishing a component? If so can you can you please explain why you would want to do this as you'll be changing Tridions default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i am asking question how to avoid unpublishing a component is unpublishing the inner embeded components also in Tridion 2011 SP1.The code which i have written is not working on Unpubilshing the component. I mean when we click on the Unpulish button which event should be triggered? Currently i am writing code for UnPublishEventArgs,but which is not working.

Comment: Please use the answers only for an actual answer, if you want to reply on a comment, then use the comments for that. I have edited your question to reflect what you have said, but I'm still wondering what exactly is going wrong as you don't fully mention this. Can you confirm the event code is executed (do you see the logging statement appear when you unpublish for example)? Also could you supply some more detail on your Component/Schema and what you see happening, is it Dynamic Component Presentations that are unpublished or Pages etc.?

Comment: Have you verified that this code gets executed?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean linked components for "embedded components," you do not have to do anything to avoid unpublishing components your unpublished component links to.

When unpublishing a Component, pages and dynamic Component Presentations that use the Component are unpublished.

The exception would be binaries (multimedia components), but these aren't really "unpublished" per se. Managed multimedia components are removed when they're no longer in use on the delivery side.